# Java: how do I print 2 System.out.println's on the same console line

Tags: java

I would like to print two things (println) on the same console line. How would I do this?

example code:

```
System.out.println("test");
System.out.println("test1");
```

and in the console I would like to see:

> test test1

Comment: Just remove the `ln` in `println` :)

Answer (score 5):

Change the first one to `System.out.print()` and add a space like,

```
System.out.print("test ");
System.out.println("test1");
```

Alternatively, you could potentially use formatted output like

```
System.out.printf("%s %s%n", "test", "test1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.out.print("your text")` to print without a linebreak

Answer (score 0):

`println` prints a new line after the input.